# Tensordot of 2 vector fields

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, dot-product

I want to compute the element-wise tensor product of 2 tensors of the shape `(1144,3)` meaning I want to compute the tensordot along the second axis if I understood it correctly.

I'd expect my result to be of the shape `(1144,3,3)`.

I am currently trying to achieve this using numpys [`tensordot()`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) function, but I can't figure out the correct axes to use to get a shape of `(1144,3,3)`.

Comment: `tensordot` is an attempt to generalize `dot`.  That's `dot/inner` product over some combination of rows/columns.  Looks like you want an outer product, without any summing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for this.

```
In [30]: a
Out[30]:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [31]: np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', a, a)
Out[31]:
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 0,  2,  4]],

       [[ 9, 12, 15],
    [12, 16, 20],
    [15, 20, 25]]])
```

As `numpy.tensordot` support only 2 element `axes` this means there is no way to imitate the

`->...`-like behavior. So I don't see how this can be done with `numpy.tensordot`.